# Java Selector select() always returns the last read key

Tags: java, selector, nio

I am trying to write a TCP server that reads data sent by the client. I want to keep the client connection open after the read to be able to read any subsequent data sent.

The code I am executing is below :

```
    while(true) {
        try {
            int keysSelected = selector.select();

            System.out.println("keysSelected = " + keysSelected);
            if (keysSelected < 1) {
                continue;                    
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }


        Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

        while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
            keyIterator.remove();

            if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                processAcceptRequest(selector, key);
            } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                processQueryRequest(key);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I am experiencing is that before any clients have connected, the select call on the selector blocks. After the first client connects and writes data to the server, select continuously returns a OP_READ key, even though there is no data to read? What am I doing wrong?

The code for the read is :

```
private void processQueryRequest(SelectionKey key) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);

    SocketChannel clientChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

    try {
        byteBuffer.clear();

        while(clientChannel.read(byteBuffer) > 0) {
            byteBuffer.flip();

            Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            CharBuffer charBuffer = charset.decode(byteBuffer);

            System.out.println(charBuffer.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Regards
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `compact()` after you call `flip()` and process the data you get. You're never doing that, so you're filling the buffer, so `read()` is returning zero, so you are returning to the `select()` loop, but there is still pending data in the socket receive buffer.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to solve the problem. The key for the read is still always returned, even though the result of the read is always -1?

Comment: That means EOS so you should have closed the channel.